# (Web design) When switching pages, how do you prevent the screen from flashing white?

Tags: html, browser

This is a tricky one: When you click a link on a webpage, it usually whites out the page (Poor terminology - I know), but in some cases, if the DOM is mostly the same, it transitions between the two without flashing white. The reason I want it to transition smoothly each time is that I have an effect on the links that looks best that way...

So what exactly makes it so pages with roughly the same DOM can be switched off like so? Thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that your page whites out at the moment you navigate from one page to another page, I think you can't do anything about that since there are pretty much factors that may play a role (i.e. responsiveness of your webserver, your connection speed to the internet and so on).

However, if you really would like have a nice transition between pages, I suggest one of the following solutions:

1) Load your pages in an Iframe. When navigating from one page to another, you can show a loading message using a DIV-overlay for instance. You can hide the loading message overlay when the page have been loaded. This can be triggered using jQuery .ready() event on the child page (the parent cannot determine whether child page have been fully loaded).

Please note, in order to control the parent page from the iframed-page, all pages should be in the same domain (same-domain policy).

2) In case navigation takes place within the same app domain/website, investigate if you can do partial loading of your page content using JQuery for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because your web page is taking too long to render. To optimize the rendering speed of your page, put stylesheets at the top of the page (within `<head></head>`) and scripts at the bottom of the page (right before `</body>`). It worked for me.

Also, take a look at Yahoo's article on this topic: [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) as this is typically a way to get around the "Post back" issue that I remember with ASP.Net where usually on a form submission the screen would flicker as it reloaded the entire page.

Answer (score -4):

I don't think it is possible. The pdf converter only render follows your final html output...
Javascript always run when load or some interact with DOM. So it is not possible.

Comment: It's possible -> Like I said before, it does it in certain situations as it is, I'm curious of how to make that more consistant. I believe it could be caching but I'm not positive.